# How to redirect a subdomain in htaccess that has no subdirectories

Tags: php, .htaccess, configuration, web

I have searched on google and stackoverflow for a while, but didn't really found an answer to my question.

I want to redirect admin.domain.com to www.domain.com if there are no subdirectories or queries.

Examples that should redirect:
https://admin.domain.com
http://admin.domain.com
https://admin.domain.com/

Examples that shouldn't redirect
https://admin.domain.com/subdirectory/
https://admin.domain.com/?q=testquery

I really have no clue how to do this. I managed the trigger on subdomain, but it would also redirect if there are subdirectories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just precede the `RewriteRule` that does the redirect with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/
```

Comment: @jmz No, it wouldn't because of the query string.